# What's wrong with trying to insert this dateTime from my Java application?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jdbc

For this Java code:

```
stmt.addBatch(
                "INSERT INTO Bills (BillDateTime, Table, Item, NoAttended, Service, Payment, Total) " +
                "VALUES('" + billDateTime +  "', " + Integer.parseInt(createTableNumberOutput.toString()) +  ", '" + null + "', '" 
                + Integer.parseInt(createGuestNumberOutput.toString()) + "', " + "5" +  ", '" + 
                createPaymentTypeOutput.toString() + "', '" +  "')");
```

I get the following error:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Table, Item, NoAttended, Service, Payment, Total) VALUES('2012-03-26 11:15:8', 1' at line 1
```

The issue is not apparent to me, as MySql requires the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' for dateTime, which I have, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Table` is [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql . use backticks(**`**) around it.

Like below:

```
stmt.addBatch("INSERT INTO Bills (BillDateTime,`Table`, Item,NoAttended,Service,Payment,Total..........")
```

Answer (score 2):

Even when you fix the reserved keyword `table` issue, it still won't work. You are trying the insert `date.toString()` in the date field. (when concatenated, `toString()` gets called all non-string objects)

Instead, you should use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and call `stm.setDate(..)`. Get more familiar with the prepared statement, as it is most often the better way to go. (it also has `addBatch()`, which works in a slightly different way - you set all parameters, then add, then set again.